# PagingData adapter complete refresh

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging-3

I'm trying to implement a fragment which have an EditText and a RecyclerView. RecyclerView is filled with data coming through PagingDataAdapter

```
class SearchAdapter(
    private val showFullPeriod: Boolean,
    private val onItemClick: (Vacancy) -> Unit
) :
    PagingDataAdapter<Vacancy, SearchViewHolder>(VacancyComparator()) {
```

in my fragment I define adapter like this

```
private val seafarerAdapter = SearchAdapter(false) { vacancy -> onItemClick(vacancy) }
```

then in my onViewCreated of the fragment I apply adapter to recyclerview

```
recyclerSeafarers.adapter = seafarerAdapter
```

in my viewModel i collect data like this

```
val vacanciesData: Flow<PagingData<Vacancy>> = newPagerInstance()


private fun newPagerInstance(): Flow<PagingData<Vacancy>> = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(pageSize = vacanciesUseCase.perPage, enablePlaceholders = false),
        initialKey = 1,
        pagingSourceFactory = { BasePagingSource(vacanciesUseCase) }
).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

vacanciesUseCase is a class which is responsible for making queries to network and provide responses.

Everything works fine, until I'm not trying to change like this

```
 vacanciesUseCase.text = text
```

after that i sent and event to my fragment and make
adapter.refresh()

I works fine. The new data comes.
The problems begin when bewore changing search text I`m scrolling down so adapter loads pages 2,3,4 etc.
If I'm on the page 4. And change searching query and then call adapter.refresh() it still thinks I'm on the 4th page. It doesn't go to page 1. I can see it in logs of queries to network.

I tried recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0) before refresh but it doesn't work at all. I tried recyclerView.smoothhScrollToPosition(0). It works but not always and it scrolls really slow. I tried to make a delay between call recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0) and adapter.refresh(). It helps but it's a bad way, I think.

The only thing that helped is to make adapter a var and recreate it on textchange
So my main question is how to make PagingAdapter completely refresh and go to page 1?

Comment: For every 'invalidate' call triggered during the 'refresh' to invalidate the old data, a new paging source will be created by invoking the lambda passed in as 'pagingSourceFactory.' Please ensure that you are updating the page number properly if it is within your usecase, as you are using the same usecase instance even after calling refresh().

Comment: The page number is stored in PagingSource not in usecase. Page number goes as a parameter of usecase execute function.
Like this:
class BasePagingSource<T : Any>(
    private val useCase: IPageable<T>
) : PagingSource<Int, T>() {
    private val startingKey = 1

....

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, T> {
        val page = params.key ?: startingKey
        isFirstLoad = false
        return when (val result = useCase.execute(page)) {